# How to do multiple "match" or "match_phrase" values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

So ElasticSearch has the **terms** query, which lets me supply multiple values and return a ist of documents where field X matches any of those values.

But I want to do the same thing with **match_phrase** - i.e. return documents where field X contains a case insensitive match for a term with spaces.  I currently do it my using an or filter (see below).  But that seems like a very verbose way of doing what I want, considering that terms does something similar already.

**Current method**

It seems ridiculous that a query searching a single field for one of three values should be 33 lines long.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
       "filter": {
           "or": {
              "filters": [
                 {
                     "query": {
                         "match_phrase": {
                            "myField1": "My first search phrase"
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     "query": {
                         "match_phrase": {
                            "myField1": "My second search phrase"
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     "query": {
                         "match_phrase": {
                            "myField1": "My third search phrase"
                         }
                     }
                 }
              ]
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is better answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020178/executing-a-multi-match-phrase-query-in-elastic-search/30020384#30020384

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After a long night trying to figure this out myself I came up with this:

```
"query" : {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "match_phrase": {
                      "myField1": "My first search phrase"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "match_phrase": {
                      "myField1": "My second search phrase"
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: hint: change to `must` to do `AND` condition operator, `should` is like using `OR`

Answer (score 17):

[Query string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) would be helpful here  something on these lines

```
   {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "myField1",
          "query": "\"My first search phrase\" OR \"My second search phrase\" OR \"My third search phrase\""
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can also look in many fileds and use the AND orperator : `"query_string": { "query": "fieldOne:(\"foo\" OR \"bar\") AND fieldTwo:(\"foobar\")" }`

Answer (score 3):

The query in Elastic-Search Domain Specific Language (DSL) is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "platform_id": "GPL13534"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "platform_id": "GPL8490"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

To find out stuff like this easily, use the Kibana interface:

[image]

- Hit on the right-bottom enter sign to accept multiple options
- "Edit as Query DSL"

(In this example myField1 is platform_id and the search phrases are "GPL***")