# Multi-"match-phrase" query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, match-phrase

this should be obvious to me but is not. The following two-match only the second phase (in this case, `Cape Basin`)

```json
    "query": {
      "match_phrase": {
        "contents": {
          "query": "St Peter Fm",
          "query": "Cape Basin"
        }
      }
    }

    "query": {
      "match_phrase": {
        "contents": {
          "query": ["St Peter Fm", "Cape Basin"]
        }
      }
    }
```

while the following croaks with an error

```json
    "query": {
      "match_phrase": {
        "contents": {
          "query": "St Peter Fm"
        },
        "contents": {
          "query": "Cape Basin"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to match all documents that contain **either**  phrases exactly as entered.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your first query is not really a valid JSON object because you use the same field name twice.

You can use a [bool must or should query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to match both OR one of the phrases:

```json
    PUT phrase/doc/1
    {
      "text": "St Peter Fm some other text Cape Basin"
    }

    //Match BOTH
    GET phrase/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
             {"match_phrase": {"text":  "St Peter Fm"}},
             {"match_phrase": {"text":  "Cape Basin"}}
          ]
        }
     }
    }

    //Match EITHER ONE
    GET phrase/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
             {"match_phrase": {"text":  "St Peter Fm"}},
             {"match_phrase": {"text":  "Cape Basin"}}
          ]
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the invalid JSON object. Yes, that was a mistake on my part. I have clarified the question as well. Thanks for showing me how to do a `boolean and` search for all docs with the two phrases. Actually, I want all docs with either or both phrases.

Comment: Changing `bool` to `should` seems to do the trick. Many thanks for the tip in the right direction.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can do a match_phrase on multiple fields with the same query word? because i used multi_match in case of match on multiple fields for the same query word. so wondering if there is anything like multi_match for match_phrase too..  TIA :)

Comment: @ASN See my answer below, since I was asking the same thing when I found your comment.  This has worked since at least 2.3, FYI.

Answer (score 29):

It turns out you can do this by enabling phrase semantics for `multi_match`.

To do this you add a `type:` attribute to the `multi_match` syntax as below:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "quick brown fox",
      "type":       "phrase",
      "fields":     [ "subject", "message" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Once you think of it that way (vs. enabling "multi" support on other search clauses) it fits in where you'd expect.

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase

Comment: I can only assume the edits to the original changed the meaning, otherwise this wouldn't have had 10 upvotes.

Comment: fits the title of the question exactly. Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @JimK. was looking for this.

Comment: why did you mention `"type":       "phrase"`. What's the difference between the type: phrase and not mentioning it?

Comment: @Hossein - The original question specifically uses `match_phrase` which isn't the default behavior for `multi_match`.  ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html

In brief, it allows terms to be a little farther apart than immediate neighbors.