# Elastic search query using python list

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

How do I pass a list as query string to match_phrase query?

This works:

> {"match_phrase": {"requestParameters.bucketName": {"query": "xxx"}}},

This does not:

```
        {
            "match_phrase": {
                "requestParameters.bucketName": {
                    "query": [
                        "auditloggingnew2232",
                        "config-bucket-123",
                        "web-servers",
                        "esbck-essnap-1djjegwy9fvyl",
                        "tempexpo",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have to tried using `bool` query ? Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30020384/11774805

Comment: My question is, does match_phrase supports list like this: {"match_phrase": {"text":  ["St Peter Fm", "Cape Basin"]}} ? Something like multi_match but for search term instead of fields.

Comment: Using "query_string" is a good workaround. My question is why "match_phrase" does not support a list?

Comment: Why do you need `match_phrase` if you're only searching a single token?

Comment: I am trying to search for 5 bucket names using "OR" parameter. The question is how to keep the query as concise as possible. It will be very useful if elastic supports the syntax shown in the question.

Comment: I got that, but `match_phrase` is for matching tokens that follow each other. You're querying individual tokens, so the `terms` query would probably fit your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match_phrase` simply does not support multiple values.

You can either use a `should` query:

```json
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "requestParameters.bucketName": {
              "value": "auditloggingnew2232"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "requestParameters.bucketName": {
              "value": "config-bucket-123"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

or, as @Val pointed out, a `terms` query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "requestParameters.bucketName": [
        "auditloggingnew2232",
        "config-bucket-123",
        "web-servers",
        "esbck-essnap-1djjegwy9fvyl",
        "tempexpo"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

that functions like an `OR` on exact terms.

I'm assuming that 1) the bucket names in question are unique and 2) that you're not looking for partial matches. If that's the case, plus if there are barely any analyzers set on the field `bucketName`, `match_phrase` may not even be needed! `terms` will do just fine. The difference between `term` and `match_phrase` queries is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26003404/8160318).